# How AMCL get encoder information

Tags: navigation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am working on AMCL recently. I am wondering how amcl receives odometry information from encoder. From the wiki, I found that amcl receives transform between odom and base_link. Is it the way to receive odometry information from encoder? So is there other node broadcast tf between odom and base_link?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248518/how-amcl-get-encoder-information/) by [MINGLIBRIAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/28378/minglibrian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes. AMCL gets odometry information from the TF transform from odom to base_link.

This transform usually comes from some hardware on your robot, so the node that publishes the transform is specific to each robot. There's a [navigation Odometry tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom) which describes how to publish the odometry transform from your encoder values.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MINGLIBRIAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/28378/minglibrian/) on 2016-11-22**:
Thank you so much. If I understand correctly, the transform between odom and base_link broadcasted by some hardware should be varying as robot moves, right? And I saw that the parent frame of base_link is not odom but base_footprint, so what is the difference between the two frames? Thank you again!

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-11-23**:
Some robots use different frame names, or they'll have intermediate frames between odom and base_link. In that case the hardware usually publishes the transform between odom and its direct child frame (in this case base_footprint).